# How to deploy Gradle Project in Tomcat, it doesn't worked

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle

I built a Java project with Gradle, It can run successfully in Intellij's Tomcat. But when I try to deploy it on my local Tomcat, I can only open the `index.jsp`.

Here is my intellij's Tomcat, I can open every pages here, for example `/admin/index`:

```
Artifact Gradle : 1.0 : 3dmfy-1.0.war (exploded): Artifact is deployed successfully
Artifact Gradle : 1.0 : 3dmfy-1.0.war (exploded): Deploy took 4,920 milliseconds
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KGAc.png)

When I deploy it in my local Tomcat, It succeeded:

```
 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor D:\Program\Tools\Tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\3dmfy.xml

 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor D:\Program\Tools\Tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\3dmfy.xml has finished in 344 ms
```

But I get `404` error and can only open `index.jsp`, but it lost all `.css` and `.js`, like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnAzd.png)

I am confusing whether I missed some config in Tomcat's `server.xml`, or `Gradle` need some plugin to run deploy in Tomcat. Does anyone give me an advice?

Comment: Double check that all the URLs are correct; it seems on your local tomcat the app is deployed with context path `/3dmfy` while it was just `/` before

Comment: I added `3dmfy.xml` in `\Tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost` and I use `8080` port. In Intellij, I use `80` port. Is that the mistake I made?

Comment: Not necessarily a mistake, the app is just deployed to a different context path. i.e. what was `/admin/index` should now be `/3dmfy/admin/index`. The same holds for all support files (.css, .js, ...). Usually, one writes the app in such a way, that the context path does not matter.

Comment: I think I confuse my context path and something else. I will keep working on it.